# How do I keep my body well hydrated?

Tags: water, hydration

I sweat a lot, I don't know the reason behind it and also if this is bad for me.
This is making me think that I should find ways and make some habit to keep my body well hydrated all the time.
I know that I need to drink a lot of water and most importantly I need to make it a habit so that I don't have to think much about it and just do it unconciously.

After eating it is difficult to drink more water as my stomach is already full. My idea would be to drink a lot after morning exercise when my stomach is empty or I have just taken some really light food and a little bit more before sleep and rest of the day normally.

Are there any other ways to keep the body well hydrated (I mean adding some salt to water or some solution) and does liquid food and juices help to do that?

I've never measured it but I drink 2-3 liters of water everyday.

Comment: Please see the information in this question: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1878/how-do-i-prevent-and-or-treat-dehydration

Comment: You've never measured, but you know you drink 2-3 liters of water everyday?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, hydration relies on some basic principles:

- Drink a bit of water, all the time (not at specific times)
- Under physical activity, increase frequency
- Use mild temperature water (20-22ºC is the recommended tmp. if I'm not mistaken)
  (cold water refreshes but does not hydrate, mild water hydrates but does not refresh)
- Include non-dry fruits & vegetables in your diet
- Restrict diuretic components (cafeine, alcohol)

Ideally, at least that's what I noticed in my own situation, the following symptoms will tell you whether or not you're well hydrated:

- You don't feel thirsty at any time
- You are not thirsty after a meal (well, a very salty meal will make an exception)
- And this one, very neat... If your lips are starting to crackle, even a little bit, you're dehydrated. In winter for instance, if you need that little cream to protect your lips, you're dehydrated. (I'm not living in a place where temperatures go below -5ºc or so, so maybe in Northern Canada it would be different :-))

At last, I'll remind you that the feeling of being thirsty depends of how aware of you body you are. After you start to respect these little rules you'll start to notice your dehydration *much* faster, accurately. Your body will really talk to you...

Comment: Thanks for nice info, I used to have my lips crackled most of the time...and i am not thirsty after a meal(not very salty) a but i feel thristy after excercise....

Comment: Feeling thirsty after exercise is normal I suppose, but I'd say you should drink all the time during it. Don't forget water is the oil of our body engine, without it, it breaks! Tendonitis, joints pains.. Water prevents these risks.

Comment: yes you are right, i am not very aware and alert about my body maybe because of busy IT industry lifestyle tending to be fast instead of being slow,calm and composed...I am going to take this into account and make changes.Thanks a lot again

Answer (score 0):

Your body is really good at keeping your water levels in a good range by making you thirsty. But if you know in advance that you will lose more water, drink a bit more water. People are crazy about drinking water these days. I'd say that unless you exercise more than 10 hours per week, you don't have to bother with it at all.

I used to drink all the time when exercising, then I started doing brazilian jiujitsu, wrestling in warm suits, losing tons of water, not having time to refill a lot, and you know what? I stopped drinking so much, didn't change a thing.